# Parse body from GET request using nodejs, express, body-parser?

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

Is it possible to retrieve the `body` contents using `express`?

I started by trying `body-parser` but that doesn't seem to work with `GET`. Are there any modules which would work?

```
var express = require('express'),
  bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
  PORT = process.env.PORT || 4101,
  app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.route('/')
  .get(function(req, res) {
    respond(req, res, 'GET body contents:\n');
  })
  .post(function(req, res) {
    respond(req, res, 'POST body contents:\n');
  });

app.listen(PORT, function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('err on startup ' + err);
    return;
  }
  console.log('Server listening on port ' + PORT);
});

/*
 * Send a response back to client
 */
function respond(req, res, msg){
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.write(msg);
  res.end(JSON.stringify(req.body, null, 2));
}
```

This is response from `GET`:

```
GET body contents:
{}
```

And from `POST`:

```
POST body contents:
{
    "gggg": ""
}
```

Comment: Primo, GET request's does not have body

Comment: take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body

Comment: GET request's does not have body. Use POST instead.

Comment: @bigdestroyer GET requests do allow a body

Comment: @bobbyrne01 While GETs can have a body, as per the HTTP spec, servers should ignore it, as it has no meaning. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/983458/789529). What is the server going to do with all these UUIDs? It's probable that structuring the application differently is what's needed, an ultra-long URL is unlikely to be the right tool for the job...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GET requests don't have a body, they have query strings. In order to access a query string in expressJS you should use the `req.query` object.

```
res.end(JSON.stringify(req.query, null, 2));
```

Comment: The problem is, I'd like user to submit a list of `uuids` in the `GET` request body. I will lookup these `uuids` against a db.  There could be hundreds of `uuids` passed, should these all be put into `query` string?

Comment: @bobbyrne01 Why can't you use a POST request then? There is a limitation on the length of a query string, but it's fairly large

Comment: I can use `POST`, but was trying to remain as RESTful as possible. I understand the limitation on length is large, but theres a possibility I could hit it.

Comment: It all depends on architecture and requirements. For example you can limit the number of items that can be processed in a batch, or you can make the whole process async, where you post the batch and then check the status of the batch

Comment: @bobbyrne01 If you want to remain RESTful, use GET headers. They achieve the same effect as POST (etc) body. Have a look at https://www.owasp.org/index.php/REST_Security_Cheat_Sheet#Sensitive_information_in_HTTP_requests

Comment: GET Statements can have Body. This was changed in 2014.