# Accessing WSL2 Vue.js server (localhost:8080) exposing NATted IP number externally

Tags: vue.js, ubuntu, vuejs2, localhost, wsl-2

Some background, just so you know what I am trying to achieve before someone suggests that what I want is not what I want: I am developing a Vue.js 3 service, with a little Python (Flask) backend. Both components run on (Ubuntu) WSL2 and Windows 10. Everything has worked fine referring to http://localhost:8080 (Vue) and http://localhost:5000 (Flask) respectively (URLs work out of the box from my Chrome on Windows without further configuration).
My problem is that I could also use exposing 8080 with the IP number on my LAN to test the UI I'm building with my phone (inspiration [here](https://youtu.be/TaPdgj8mucI?t=237)). Trying to do this, in turn, lead me [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yCK3easuYm4&t=327s&ab_channel=DavidBombal) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IL7Jd9rjgrM&ab_channel=DavidBombal)).

All good? Not so much, because:

Ubuntu:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal

$ ip addr | grep eth0
4: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
inet 172.24.76.40/20 brd 172.24.79.255 scope global eth0
```

The Flask server works (here's Ubuntu, but same thing from the Windows Powershell)

```
$ curl http://172.24.76.40:5000
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test file upload</title>
        <style>
body {
   :
```

But, sort of inexplicably to me:

```
$ curl http://172.24.76.40:8080
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.24.76.40 port 8080: Connection refused
```

yet:

```
$ curl http://localhost:8080
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">
```

Of course `http://172.24.76.40:8080` won't be accessible from Chrome on Windows 10 either.

Flask (port 5000) is accessible from Chrome on Windows and even from my Android phone (with the Windows IP of course: `http://192.168.1.156:5000` ) on the same Lan (that's after I went into the Windows Firewall to open the port and did this port forwarding in the powershell:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=5000 listenaddress=0.0.0.0 connectport=5000 connectaddress=172.24.76.40
```

Dear network wizards, am I going crazy? What am I missing?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the solution, and believe me, this was a gotcha of major proportion, as the solution was to be found in a rather different place than I had expected.

As I had the backend and the front-end running on the same localhost, CORS had raised its ugly head and given me a hard time. I had addressed that issue with [this approach](https://vuejsdevelopers.com/lessons/dev-server-proxy/1/) some time back.  Little did I know that this was also introducing such a nasty side effect that had gone unnoticed for quite a while (making the server at that IP appear unreachable!). In short, it was not a network issue, albeit it damn sure looked like one!

My solution was to change the `vue.config.js` file from this:

```
devServer: {
   proxy: 'http://localhost:5000/',
   host: 'localhost'
},
```

to this:

```
devServer: {
  proxy: {
    "/upload": {
      target: "http://localhost:5000"
    }
  }
},
```

I am sure that React.js developers may find themselves in a similar situation. Now you know where to look at. Same goes for users of other frameworks.

Comment: Thank you for your edit NotTheDroids, I was not aware of the rule. Honest. My problem is that I hate it when SO tells me that I cannot do this or that because of reputation. I wasn't trying to do anything funky,